# Why are div positions different depending on wether there is text inside?

Tags: css

I don't understand why the child div boxes don't get neatly aligned when some contain text and others don't.

Here is an example:

```
<html><head>
<style>
.parent {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 80%;
    border: 2px solid #f00;
}
.child {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #00f;
}
</style>
</head><body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child">Text1</div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child">Text2</div>
    </div>
</body></html>
```

The child div boxes seem to choose their vertical position depending on wether there is text inside the box.

How can fix this and have them being placed at the same vertical position? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the vertical-align property when using inline-block.

```html
<html><head>
<style>
.parent {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 80%;
    border: 2px solid #f00;
}
.child {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 20%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #00f;
}
</style>
</head><body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child">Text1</div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child">Text2</div>
    </div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the `vertical-align` property of child `div`s. Due to it's inline-block display, it's positions are modified by text, which is also inline displayed. Try something like this:

```css
.parent {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 80%;
    border: 2px solid #f00;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
.child {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #00f;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

```html
<html><head>

</head><body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child">Text1</div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child">Text2</div>
    </div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`inline-block`s by default align along their baseline, which - if they contain text - is the last line of text in there. If they don't contain text, the baseline is the bottom of the DIV - therefore the rather strange alignment in your example.

To avoid this, you can use `vertical-align` settings like `top` or `bottom`. Below I used `top` for your example:

```css
.parent {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 80%;
  border: 2px solid #f00;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #00f;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child">Text1</div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child">Text2</div>
</div>
```